# Unable to use angular factory cross routes

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I'm trying to create a factory and use it cross routes in each controller but apparently I'm doing something wrong...

**The app:**

```
var app = angular.module('sam', ['ngRoute', 'ngGrid', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

**The factory**

```
app.factory("User",function(){
        return {};
    });
```

**The routes**

```
// configure our routes
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // route for the main page which will direct to the buildings page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'web/pages/buildings.html',
                controller  : 'mainController',
                controllerAs : 'buildings'
            })

    });
```

**The controller**

```
app.controller('mainController', ['$filter', '$http','$log', function($filter, $http, $log, User){
        $log.log('hello!!!!!', User);
}]);
```

This prints : `hello!!!!! undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing 'User' in your controller.

```
app.controller('mainController', ['$filter', '$http','$log', **'User',** function($filter, $http, $log, User){
        $log.log('hello!!!!!', User);
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include `User` as part of injection array

```
controller('mainController', ['$filter', '$http','$log', function($filter, $http, $log, User){
```

Should be:

```
controller('mainController', ['$filter', '$http','$log','User', function($filter, $http, $log, User){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.factory("User",function(){
    return {
           show:function(){
                alert('Factory called')
           }
};
});




app.controller('mainController', ['$filter', '$http','$log','User', function($filter, $http, $log, User){

  //that is the way you can call your factory
  // you can call this factory function in any controller by injecting it.

      User.show(); //will popup alert window.
```

}]);